# How to verify which zend-* modules need to be loaded?

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I'm wondering how I can check which modules I need to load in my modules array (`config/modules.config.php`).

The autoloader does not seem to load all which were installed using composer or some are already included in ZF3 itself and they conflict when it tries to load them again.

Comment: This is actually a good question and need first answer on why and what you get by loading a module(s) in config.

Answer (score 0):

All modules which you install using composer should be registered in `autoloader`. But the problem, the modules is registered in `config/modules.config.php` or not.

If you use [Zend Component Installer](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-component-installer/), you don't need to think the Zend Modules must be loaded in `modules.config.php` or not. Because Zend Component Installer will prompt you to inject the module in modules configuration (`config/modules.config.php`) or not while install it using composer. This very helpful feature. It works by read `extra.zf.component` key in `composer.json` from installed module. Here is the sample from [Zend Form](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/release-2.10.2/composer.json#L59). While  you add `Zend\\Form` to `composer.json`, then run `composer update`, `composer` will prompt you to inject this module to `config/modules.config.php` or not.

If you don't use Zend Component Installer, I think you can check `extra.zf.component` key in `composer.json` from installed module. And add it manually to your `config/modules.config.php`.

FYI, if your application using [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/release-3.0.2), it has use Zend Component Installer.

Comment: OK this is helpfull, but will the Zend Component Installer not ask for this inject question when it's not needed to have it in there, like Zend\View can't be in your modules.config.php because then it will error on the second load. So if you install zend-view it won't be asked to be injected I assume ?

Comment: Yes, it won't be asked. Becaused the key `extra.zf.component` doesn't exist in `Zend\View` composer.json https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/release-2.9.0/composer.json